# Information Needed from apple after submission ios app

Tags: ios, app-store

I have submitted app to app store and app status came like 'Metadata Rejected' and following review status.

> We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because
>   we need a demo account to fully access your app features.
>
> Please provide demo account details in the Review Notes section of the
>   Version Information for your app. Please ensure that the information
>   you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the
>   functionality of your app features.
>
> You can provide demo account information, including passwords, in the
>   Review Notes section of your iTunes Connect App Information.
>
> While your iTunes Connect Application State shows as Metadata
>   Rejected, we don't require a new binary to correct this issue. Please
>   visit iTunes Connect, Manage Your Applications. Select your app, then
>   click View Details of the desired version. Click the Edit button next
>   to Version Information to edit the Review Notes for your app, then
>   click "Save".

Comment: I have one webview in my app and need to login to see entire content..Is this a problem? Should i provide login credentials?

Comment: Yes - you need to provide them with information how to access all the content. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the description, it seems like your application needs some specific account to login to use application features. So, Apple people do not have access to your application until you provide them the testing account to log into the application.

You do not need to re-submit the application binary. You just need to provide account information to access your application. That is what they mean to say in description.

Please let me know if this information helps you.

Comment: thanks for quick reply Born..I will send test user credentials to apple

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you like the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

you must communicate a credential for the demo section so apple can try this